# SuperObject JSON Error

Tags: json, delphi

```
procedure TForm1.kClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  selected: String;
  json: ISuperObject;
begin
  j:=0;
  json := TSuperObject.Create('{}');
  json.S['slide']:= '1';

  for  i:= 0 to Dest.Count-1 do
    begin
      if rects[i].Tag = 1 then
        begin
          json.A['selected'].S[j]:= IntToStr(i+1);
          Inc(j);

        end;
    end;

  req.Method:= TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  req.AddBody(json.AsJSON(true), ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
  req.Execute;
end;
```

Here is ShowMessage(json.AsJSON(true)); output:

[image]

Node.js (Server) ERROR:

[image]

Node.js codes:

```
app.post('/api/db', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

I can send as a parameter like :

```
req.AddParameter('JSON', json.AsJSON(true));
```

But i do not know is it true approaching to send json, because when i sent like this, it sent as a string. But i want to send as a json type. But i could not. Anyone can help me?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i fix codes top of the question?

Comment: [`AsJSON`](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/source/browse/superobject.pas#554) returns a `SOString` type, so you are actually sending a string. Moreover, the [`AddParameter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.AddParameter) method accepts `TJSONObject` and has nothing to do with `ISuperObject`.

Comment: @TLama how do i change type of ISuperObject (json) to JSON format

Comment: What is wrong with that code? What do you expect it to do? How does it fail?

Comment: If you would like to use the overload which accepts `TJSONObject`, you would need to use the built-in Delphi JSON support (since I don't think that SuperObject library can cast to `TJSONObject` object). In all cases, `TJSONObject != ISuperObject`. ([`AddBody`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.AddBody) of course supports also only `TJSONObject`).

Comment: @TLama oh okay, i understand now. I will send as a parameter, i think no need to convert it. David Heffernan I just wanted to learn why i could not send JSON format, and how to convert it, TLama explained it.

Comment: What do you mean by "JSON format"? You seem to think that JSON is something other than text.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you' re right, i thought it is different than the text

Comment: Well, it is not. JSON is just text.

Comment: the puzzle now completed in my mind, thank you :)